# Certain Lagrange multiplier type of problem; don't know how to proceed without breaking laws of math

Tags: calculus

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the max and min values of $f$ subject to the given constraint.

$f(x,y) = 4x^3+y^2; 2x^2+y^2=1$

$ \vec\nabla F(x,y) = \lambda\vec\nabla G(x,y)$

So I take the partials of both and set them equal to each other:

$12x^2=4x\lambda; 2y = 2y\lambda$

Now here is where I am confused about: Am I able to just divide both sides by $2y$ on the second equation? My teacher would bring up situations about how $y$ could equal $0$, and in that case he does a bunch of stuff to solve it. But then other times he *doesn't* do that and just divides and ends up with something like $2x/y = \lambda$. It makes just no sense to me.

Comment: for the equation, $2y = 2y\lambda$ in general, $y=0$ is one solution. If $y$ is not zero, then you can divide by $y$ to get $\lambda =1$ for any value of $y$. There is no case, to my knowledge, where you could "ignore" that a variable may be zero during division unless it is known that it is not zero in some way (e.g. given in the problem, zero does not belong to the domain of the function, etc.). In general this case is dealt with by having 2 (or more) cases. One case for $y=0$ and the other case(s) for other values of $y$.

Comment: So basically I think I got it: one case would be $y = 0$ and so I would plug that into the constraint, giving me x, and a coordinate would be $(x,0)$. Then I make another case where $y$ isn't $0$, solve for $\lambda$ (which equals 1 in this case), plug it into x to get a number, then plug that in the constraint to get y and a second coordinate. Then I plug both those coordinates in to $f(x,y)$ and compare them.

Is that right?

Comment: I guess this is correct, unless you get a more professional answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have two cases to consider : either $y=0$ or $\lambda=1$.

If $\lambda=1$, then $x=\frac 13$ from the first derivative and then $y^2=\frac 79$ from the constraint. So, for such a point $4x^3 +y^2=\frac{25}{27}$.

Now, if $y=0$,  then $x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ from the constraint. So, for such a point $4x^3 +y^2=\pm\sqrt{2}$. Compare the result to $\frac{25}{27}$.

Comment: So is there any problem that I can just ignore the case of something like that? For example, I think my professor would skip the case when the constraint was a circle or something, because technically on the perimeter of a circle $x$ and $y$ can't equal zero. Would it be okay to skip that in this case?